# How to have a dropdown with checkbox as options in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

[image: Dropdown with checkbox options]

I need to include checkboxes as options in dropdown menu in Angular.

Comment: you could try javascript html and css.... or is that not expected since you're using angular.  c'mon try it yourself, you might actually like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to :

- http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-multi-select-dropdown

Maybe it helps u!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Uib dropdown.

Sample code

Select
                                 
                                 
                                     
                                         

                                     
                                     
                                         {{team.filter}}